# SQL Select if any child or subchild has a value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, Categories and Articles. Articles have a FK relating them to a category. The Category table is hierarchical, so each category has a CAT_FK_Parent pointing to another Category, or NULL if it is a top level category.

What I am trying to do is sort the Articles by Category, and only display categories from the list that either have an article directly associated with it, or categories that have a child/subchild that have an Article associated.

So right now my code looks like:

```
SELECT  TOP 1000 [CAT_PK]
  ,[CAT_Description]
  ,[CAT_FK_Parent]
  ,[CAT_CanHaveChildren]
  ,[CAT_EMP_FK]
  ,[CAT_Action]
  ,[CAT_Active]
  ,[CAT_Autoclose]
  ,[CAT_ROL_Name]
FROM [TicketCategories]
WHERE 
((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM WikiArticles WHERE WAR_CAT_FK = CAT_PK AND WAR_Active=1) ) > 0
```

This returns categories with a WAR_CAT_FK equal to themselves, but does not take children into account.

Since Categories can have any number of child levels under them, I assume I need some kind of recursive function to do a count of all children, but I'm having trouble finding resources for recursive WHERE conditions.

Comment: did you mean "or categories that have a child/subchild that have a article associated."

Answer (score 0):

You should use joins to do this not a sub-query, much faster.

- First join to Articles
- Then join to Children categories that have articles
- Then check to see if one of the join to article exists (is not null)
- Finally Group By or DISTINCT to remove duplicate rows

.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000
   TC.CAT_PK
  ,TC.CAT_Description
  ,TC.CAT_FK_Parent
  ,TC.CAT_CanHaveChildren
  ,TC.CAT_EMP_FK
  ,TC.CAT_Action
  ,TC.CAT_Active
  ,TC.CAT_Autoclose
  ,TC.CAT_ROL_Name
FROM TicketCategories TC
LEFT JOIN WikiArticles WA ON TC.WAR_CAT_FK = WA.CAT_PK AND WA.WAR_Active=1
LEFT JOIN TicketCategories Child ON TC.CAT_PK = Child.CAT_FK_Parent
LEFT JOIN WikiArticles CWA ON Child.WAR_CAT_FK = CWA.CAT_PK AND CWA.WAR_Active=1
WHERE 
  COALESCE(WA.CAT_PK,CWA.CAT_PK) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This works well for now, but it only goes one layer down in children, so if a child has a child that has an article it doesn't get picked up, hence the recursive function.

Comment: if you need tree hierarchy in sql then recursive is a bad way to implement it... if you db has any size at all it will get very very slow.  SQL Server supports this with special data types.